# I can't access my input field in my controllar - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using the Ionic framework which uses AngularJS and I can't access my input field "groupName" in my controller, I just get "undefined".

I thought using ng-model would inject it in the scope of my controller?

```
<ion-pane>
<ion-header-bar align-title="left" class="bar-positive">
    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="button" ng-click="saveNewGroup()">Save</button>
    </div>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>
    <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="groupName">
        </label>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

And the code in my controller:

```
$scope.saveNewGroup = function() {
    console.log($scope.groupName); // prints "undefined" all the time
};
```

Comment: Do you add ng-controller to your desired html-tag?

Comment: No since I'm using Ionic I set the controller in the ui-router file

Comment: ng-model assign value to var groupName. Then you need write groupName not groupName.text.  console.log($scope.groupName)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be added in scope anywhere + you aren't even passing it to the function. So, there's that.  In other words, defined $scope.groundName in your controller  and then you will find that it binds. then you should be able to log out groupName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Define $scope.groupName in your controller

It seems like you didn't define it in your controller so you are trying to access an undefined variable. Define it, and apply the correct controller to the model and you will find it data-binding properly.

Cheers.

EDIT: Glad it worked.

[image]

Comment: This solved it, thanks. Question: I set $scope.groupName to an empty object in my controller and now it works fine. How come I have to do this? I thought Angular would "fetch" the ng-model attribute and inject it into the scope automatically?

Comment: A: It should, but for some reason this is causing an issue. I've had similar issues with ionic making me crazy. Developing a phonegap app with ionic. I locally tested your code, and it works fine... Let me paste it for you so you can test it